# Android Studio : checkout new branch for a subproject

Tags: git, android-studio

I have an android project whose directory structure looks like this:

```
A
|-B
|-C
|-D
```

`A` is my main git project. It clones other git projects `B`, `C` and `D` as its subdirectories via a script.
When I import project `A` in android studio, It shows git info like remote branches for project `A` only but not for `B`, `C` and `D`. When I open terminal and run following command in directory `B`, it shows:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url

git@remote_url_of_B
```

It seems like `B` is not attached to git inside android studio. How can I attach `B` to git inside android studio and then checkout a new branch only for `B` subproject.

I am using Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2

Comment: i'm not entirely sure if this really has anything to do with android studio (or android), i believe android studio just runs git and is irrelevant here, so you could perhaps get better and faster replies if you were to remove the android studio tag, not entirely sure though, just as a suggestion if you find yourself waiting days for an answer

Comment: "It clones other git projects B, C and D as its subdirectories via a script." Have you considered using actual [git-submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)? If git understands what is going on in your project there is a chance android-studio might do so as well.

Comment: It is showing in Android studio -> Terminal. but not in IDE GUI.

Comment: I found the solution. B,C and D directories were added in .gitignore file. After removing them from file and Invalidating caches & Restart, issue is solved.